# Dojo Ajax post to send non form data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dojo

I have a requirement where I need to send a JSON Array along with the form data in an ajax post call using Dojo `xhrPost`. This JSON Array is not part of the form that is being submitted through this post call. Any suggestions on how to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [dojo.formToJson](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/formToJson.html#dojo-formtojson) to transform your form data into JSON and then add the result to the already existing JSON values in your JSON Array, finally posting the JSON Array to the server.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of the same. Is it possible to attach a JSON data with form data? For example: dojo.xhrPost({
          form : formName,
     sync : true,
     handleAs : "text",
    postData: "&jsonData=" + extraJsonDataNeeded,

Comment: I'm sure there is, for example you could add it dynamically as some sort of string value of a new, added form element. But I don't think dojo has something for that, so this would mean manually encoding before doing the POST, and again manually decoding on the server. So I'd prefer to let dojo do this with `formToJson' :)